# Getting items in MySql table from 2 different attributes

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have setup a way in NodeJS w/ Sequelize using MySQL to get the items from a table using the id of each item (which works), but I am also trying to get same items by date instead of id. Below I have snippets of the code I wrote and what I've tried already.

**Controller**

Here the FindOne function works but not the FindOneDate even though they are the same except the latter substitutes date for id.

```
// Find a single Menu Item with an id
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  Menus.findByPk(id, { include: MenuItems })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: `Error retrieving menu with id: ${id}`,
      });
    });
};

// Find a single Menu Item with an date
exports.findOneDate = (req, res) => {
  const { date } = req.params;
  
  Menus.findByDate(date, { include: MenuItems })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).sned({
        message: `Error retrieving menu with date: ${date}`,
      });
    }); 
};
```

**Route**

Here I write the router get request for the date the same as I do for id. I have tried changing the route to /date/:date but that doesn't do much either.

```
// Retrieve a single Menu Item with id
  router.get('/:id', menus.findOne);

// Retrieve a single Menu Item with date
router.get('/:date', menus.findOneDate);
```

Here is a picture of me trying to use a date in the request thru postman but I get nothing back and this is what my console looks like:
[image: Console Log]

I am not sure why in the console it compares the date I give to the id. I'm looking for any help or guidance on how to solve this, please let me know if you have any ideas or have questions.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it compares the data you gave to the ID is because of `/:id` and `/:date`. For express it's same route. Since you put ID route before Date route, when someone makes a request (for example) `/asdasd` it hits `/:id` first so it runs menu.findOne. You need to change to something like this

```
// Retrieve a single Menu Item with id
router.get('/:id', menus.findOne);

// Retrieve a single Menu Item with date
router.get('date/:date', menus.findOneDate);
```

And when you want to find by date you just make a request to `date/${your-date}`
By the way I don't think there's `Model.findByDate` function in sequelize. Maybe you should try `Model.findAll` or `Model.findOne`.

```
Menus.findOne({
    where: {
       date //I don't know how your Menu modal looks like so let's just assume it has "date" column
    },
    include: MenuItems })
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).sned({
        message: `Error retrieving menu with date: ${date}`,
      });
    });
```